# I or me after a being or linking verb

Tags: conjunctions, word-order, pronouns, prepositional-phrases

When indicating participants (as in a picture), which is correct; "This is Fred and me." or "This is Fred and I." ? (And, I know my punctuation is incorrect here.)

Answer (score 0):

This is Fred and me.

This is Fred and I.

'I' is a subject pronoun and 'me' is an object pronoun. The use of an object pronoun as a complement of 'be' is more idiomatic and common.

So both these sentences are grammatical, but the former is more common and idiomatic, and the latter is a bit formal.

Comment: When we say _This is Fred and me_, we are typically referring to the image in a photo or similar, so singular agreement is fine.

Comment: @BillJ,  You are right. This is my brother Andrew and his wife Claire (The Free Dictionary). I have edited my answer accordingly. Thanks.